# When to interpolate in benchmarking expressions

Tags: julia

The **BenchmarkTools** documentation recommends interpolating global variables into benchmarking expressions. However, the gap in run times for the example that they provide seems to have closed considerably. In [their example](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl/blob/master/doc/manual.md#interpolating-values-into-benchmark-expressions), they have a global variable `A = rand(1000)`, and they compare `@benchmark [i*i for i in A]` to `@benchmark [i*i for i in $A]`, and get `13.806 μs` versus `1.348 μs`, respectively. However, when I run that example now, the run times are very close:

```
julia> using Statistics, BenchmarkTools

julia> A = rand(1000);

julia> median(@benchmark [i*i for i in A])
BenchmarkTools.TrialEstimate: 
  time:             892.821 ns
  gctime:           0.000 ns (0.00%)
  memory:           7.95 KiB
  allocs:           2

julia> median(@benchmark [i*i for i in $A])
BenchmarkTools.TrialEstimate: 
  time:             836.075 ns
  gctime:           0.000 ns (0.00%)
  memory:           7.95 KiB
  allocs:           2
```

Here's my version info:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.1.1
Commit 55e36cc (2019-05-16 04:10 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)
```

Is interpolation in benchmarks still necessary? Any idea why the run times are so similar now? Can anyone provide a different example where the run times are different by a factor much greater than one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BenchmarkTools is in an arms race against the compiler — on multiple fronts!

The difference between the two expressions is equivalent to the difference between these two functions:

```
# @benchmark [i*i for i in A]
f1() = [i*i for i in A]

# @benchmark [i*i for i in $A]
f2(X) = [i*i for i in X]
```

In other words, using a `$` treats the value as an *argument* instead of a hard-coded constant or global.  Since `A` is a global but not constant, `f1()` is *type-unstable*.  Of course Julia has been getting better and better at dealing with type-instabilities and it appears that this is yet another place where you're no longer paying the cost for it.

There are times where not using a `$` will actually give deceivingly fast results because Julia will hard-code the value and may do some sort of constant propagation that *over-specializes* on the exact value you're benchmarking.  Here's an example that shows both directions on

```
julia> x = 0.5; # non-constant global

julia> @btime sin(x);
  20.106 ns (1 allocation: 16 bytes)

julia> @btime sin($x);
  5.413 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime sin(0.5); # constant literal!
  1.818 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime sin($0.5);
  5.416 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```